# Define Pydentic class for nested(and incremented) Json

Tags: python, json, fastapi, pydantic

I have following json response from an api endpoint. and I want to created an equivalent pydentic class for the same.

```
{
 "AllSeries": 
  {
    "s1": {
        "s_id": 1,
        "s_name": "Apple"
    },
    "s2": {
        "s_id": 2,
        "s_name": "Basket"
    },
    "s3": {
        "s_id": 3,
        "s_name": "Commerce"
    },
  }
}
```

First I tried following but that didn't worked:

```
class AllSModel(BaseModel):
     s_id: int
     s_name: int


class StatesModel(BaseModel):
    all_s: AllSModel= None
```

Then I take a reference from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302056/define-a-pydantic-nested-model)

```
class JsonObject(BaseModel):
    __root__:  Dict[int, str]

class AssociatedObject(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str]


class ObjectProperties(BaseModel):
    s_id: Optional[int]
    s_name: Optional[str]


class BaseObject(BaseModel):
    """
    Represents an object at the furthest depth
    of the nested structure
    """
    properties: ObjectProperties = ObjectProperties()
```

But throws following error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for JsonObject
__root__
value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

This is how my def look like :

```
def getResponseJSON():
  ----- more code ------  
  response = requests.post(decResponseURL,headers=headers, params=payload, verify=True)
  
  print(type(response))
  ''' Response is already posted in question'''
  ------ Error throws on below line ----
  b = JsonObject.parse_obj(response)
  print(b) 
  ---- if I turn response into json like below ---
  my_json_object = JsonObject.parse_obj(response.json())
  print(my_json_object)
  
  ---- then it throws following error ----
    line 183, in getResponseJSON
    my_json_object = JsonObject.parse_obj(response.json())
  File "/home/userpath/environments/my_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
 ----------------------------
  return "r_json"
```

I suspect whether my modal is not created correctly. Please help into rectifying above code.

Comment: what throws the error - just defining the models or some attempt to create an instance? If the latter, how does the actual code/payload throwing the error look like? I suspect you're not sending data for the `JsonObject` and since it's not marked as `Optional` then it throws the error as I'd expect.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko : I am trying to attach response to pydantic class for later use (store into db).  updated question

Comment: ok but what is in the payload?! If the dictionary `{"AllSeries": ...}` on top of your question then this dictionary is not matching what `JsonObject` excepts thus the error. If some other data then you have to show the data as I asked in my previous comment. It's impossible to figure out what's wrong without seeing your code and the data.

Comment: payload ={'auth_key':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','response_str':'encrypted_str'}. the encrypted_str later decrypted and becomes {"AllSeries":...} nested json. So,this dictionary is not matching what JsonObject expects.  Hope this clears your doubt

Comment: kindly leave the comment why it is down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse specific json you could use structure like that:

```
class AllSModel(BaseModel):
    s_id: int
    s_name: str

class Inter(BaseModel):
    __root__: dict[str, AllSModel]

class StatesModel(BaseModel):
    AllSeries: Inter = None
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kosciej16: I followed your model and almost got it working except when I try printing:   print(Inter.parse_obj(response.json())) 
it is raising following error:   
raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Where the response comes from? And what is the content of `response.json()`?

Comment: response comes from api endpoint and content is "AllSeries" (given already in question)

Comment: Then you should use `AllSeries.parse_obj(...)`