# Pydantic validation in python

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

How can I validate this kind of argument in fastapi endpoint:

```
{
"filters": {
            "simple": [[str,str,any],...], 
            "combined": [[str,str,str], ...]
             }
}
```

keyword "simple" and "combined" are fixed
and should exactly be the same and each one contains just list of 3  str

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70302056/define-a-pydantic-nested-model

Answer (score 1):

You can use conlist inside the List type

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, conlist
from typing import List


class SimpleCombine(BaseModel):
    simple :  List[conlist(str, min_length=3, max_length=3)]
    combined : List[conlist(str, min_length=3, max_length=3)]

class Filter(BaseModel):
    filters :  SimpleCombine
```

Comment: That is a good solution. Though, OP is asking for _"just a list of 3 str"_. Hence, both `min_length` and `max_length` arguments should be used for `conlist`. For example, `conlist(str, min_length=3, max_length=3)`.

Comment: @Chris yes you are right